# How to facebook share of another site url(page) from my site?

Tags: facebook, socialshare

I have implemented facebook share on

**www.prod.example.com/aboutus**.
When I do facebook share from there, is it possible to share the page that **www.example.com/aboutus**.

Already i have changed the og:url meta tag as

> `<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.example.com/aboutus">`

But its not affect anything.

**Actual result** : After share it in FB, if user clicks on it(in facebook) then it should open *www.prod.example.com/aboutus*

**Expected result** : After share it in FB, if user clicks on it(in facebook) then it should open *www.example.com/aboutus*

**www.example.com/aboutus** ----> Share it in FB ----> on click shared item, it will come back to **www.example.com/aboutus** *((default behaviour - Working))*

**www.prod.example.com/aboutus** ----> Share it in FB ----> on click shared item, it should go to **www.example.com/aboutus** *(( Expecting for this too ))*

Facebook debugger message is here,
[image]

[image]

Comment: I don’t understand the question, why can’t you just share the correct URL to begin with?

Comment: Here two scenarios i need.   

**www.example.com/aboutus** ----> Share it in FB ----> on click shared item, it will come back to **www.example.com/aboutus** ((default behaviour - Working))

**www.prod.example.com/aboutus** ----> Share it in FB ----> on click shared item, it should go to **www.example.com/aboutus** (( Expecting for this too ))

Comment: So why do you not share `www.example.com/aboutus` in the first place? What is the purpose of `www.prod.example.com/aboutus`? How do they differ?

Comment: Have you checked your OG meta tags via the debug tool already?

Comment: `www.prod.example.com/aboutus ` this is the page where I have share button. Here I have passed og:url meta data as `www.example.com/aboutus`. But its not been considered.

Comment: Totally not what I asked. What does the debug tool say?

Comment: debugger shows no errors/warning. 

Under **Redirect Path** it displays both urls as follows    

`Input URL:https://www.prod.example.com/aboutus`   

`og:url Meta Tag:http://www.example.com/aboutus`

Comment: @CBroe Facebook debug tool message added as image with the question's description.

Comment: I am not sure if it is actually supposed to work this way. `og:url` tells the scraper where to fetch the actual meta data from, but I am not sure if it is supposed to change what the actual shared link points to ... And I still can’t see why you don’t just share the actual target URL to begin with?